# Viva Topics in Teams Bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, power-virtual-agents

Can Viva Topics be enabled for a Teams Bot? (Bot Framework or PVA). I would like adaptive cards sent from a bot to utilise hashtags to attach topic cards to an adaptive card, e.g. if an adaptive card contained #Google then hovering over the tag would show a Viva Topic card for that topic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for topic mentions currently.

Currently only user mention is supported in personal scope - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cdesktop%2Cconnector-html#mention-support-within-adaptive-cards.

User mention and tag mention are supported in channel scope - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-and-group-conversations?tabs=dotnet#add-mentions-to-your-messages

You can suggest this feature on [Microsoft Teams Feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).